# How to change url so that the current HTML remains

Tags: jquery, ajax

By clicking a button, the url has to change but html should stay the same

```
$('#v-pills-profile-tab').on('click', function (event) {
   // change url
   // and html remains
})
```

Comment: *to do a little data manipulation in between* - can you provide an example?   If you "reload the page" then any js you're using to "manipulate data" will be halted.

Comment: yes it is unclear, an href links to another/the same page by default. also forcing a reload

Comment: @RamondeVries By clicking the button the url has to change but html should stay the same

Comment: the different url will visit a new page, copy paste the html of one page onto another and link towords it into the anchor

Comment: or do you mean you wish to stay on the same page, but add something to the current url so you can fire javascript/php based on the url, when you have for example `?dosomething` or `#dosomething` behind the current url

Comment: You can use `window.history.pushState`

Comment: I think it's clear that my asking for an example indicates that the question is not clear

Comment: @angel.bonev can u please provide an example of it

Comment: @D.Nursultan done you can read more from the links that I've added, this is a cool function too `history.replaceState`

Comment: Hi @D.Nursultan if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [History.pushState()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState) and [WindowEventHandlers.onpopstate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate)

```
<button id="v-pills-profile-tab"> TEST ME </button>
<script>
    $('#v-pills-profile-tab').on('click', function (event) {
        window.history.pushState({data: "some data that i will need"}, "", "my-new-url");
    });
    window.onpopstate = function (e) {               
        if (e.state) {
            console.log(e.state.data);
        } else {
            window.location.reload();
            return;
        }
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For changing url, you can simply do:

```
window.location = //Your url here
```

Also,
For reloading the page, you can simply use:

```
window.location.reload()
```

#### Note

When you change the url, the page reloads itself on its own. You don't have to reload it

Comment: by this command "window.location" html changes. Is there a way to avoid it ?